# Jmeter connectivity on Webservice working from windows and not from linux server

Tags: linux, windows, web-services, jmeter

"I tried the connectivity to the Webservice URL from jmeter running on windows and it is working fine and returning the result but when I copy that jmx file to Linux and run jmeter, I get the error as shown below.

Please note that it also has a SOAP request/data with the necessary username /password with Soap action mentioned and HTTP Authorization.

I tried telnet to the webservice (and ip) on port 443 and it is getting connected but not on any other ports.

I also tried setting the following parameters for socket connection reset, but it didn't help."

```
In user.properties file
    httpclient4.retrycount=1
    hc.parameters.file=hc.parameters

In hc.parameters file
    http.connection.stalecheck$Boolean=true

`[root@test02 bin]# ./jmeter -n -R 10.xxx.xx.xx:443 -t /jmeter_test/apache-jmeter-2.13/bin/XML_Request_Test.jmx  -l results_folder_log.jtl
Output->
Creating summariser <summary>
Created the tree successfully using /jmeter_test/apache-jmeter-2.13/bin/XML_Request_Test.jmx
Configuring remote engine: 10.xxx.xx.xx:443
error during JRMP connection establishment; nested exception is:
        java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
Failed to configure 10.xxx.xx.xx:443
Stopping remote engines
Remote engines have been stopped
Error in NonGUIDriver java.lang.RuntimeException: Following remote engines could not be configured:[10.xxx.xx.xx:443]`


Jmeter.log output
`
2016/04/26 15:23:18 INFO  - jmeter.util.JMeterUtils: Setting Locale to en_US
2016/04/26 15:23:18 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Loading user properties from: /jmeter_test/apache-jmeter-2.13/bin/user.properties
2016/04/26 15:23:18 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Loading system properties from: /jmeter_test/apache-jmeter-2.13/bin/system.properties
2016/04/26 15:23:18 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Copyright (c) 1998-2015 The Apache Software Foundation
2016/04/26 15:23:18 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Version 2.13 r1665067
2016/04/26 15:23:18 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: java.version=1.7.0_09-icedtea
2016/04/26 15:23:18 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: java.vm.name=OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
2016/04/26 15:23:18 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: os.name=Linux
2016/04/26 15:23:18 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: os.arch=amd64
2016/04/26 15:23:18 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: os.version=2.6.32-279.22.1.el6.x86_64
2016/04/26 15:23:18 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: file.encoding=UTF-8
2016/04/26 15:23:18 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Default Locale=English (United States)
2016/04/26 15:23:18 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: JMeter  Locale=English (United States)
2016/04/26 15:23:18 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: JMeterHome=/jmeter_test/apache-jmeter-2.13
2016/04/26 15:23:18 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: user.dir  =/jmeter_test/apache-jmeter-2.13/bin
2016/04/26 15:23:18 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: PWD       =/jmeter_test/apache-jmeter-2.13/bin
2016/04/26 15:23:18 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: IP: 10.xxx.xx.xx Name: hostname.ula.comcast.net FullName:  hostname.ula.comcast.net
2016/04/26 15:23:18 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Default base='/jmeter_test/apache-jmeter-2.13/bin'
2016/04/26 15:23:18 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Set new base='/jmeter_test/apache-jmeter-2.13/bin'
2016/04/26 15:23:19 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: Testplan (JMX) version: 2.2. Testlog (JTL) version: 2.2
2016/04/26 15:23:19 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: Using SaveService properties file encoding UTF-8
2016/04/26 15:23:19 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: Using SaveService properties file version 1656252
2016/04/26 15:23:19 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: Using SaveService properties version 2.8
2016/04/26 15:23:19 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: All converter versions present and correct
2016/04/26 15:23:19 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: Loading file: /jmeter_test/apache-jmeter-2.13/bin/XML_Request_Test.jmx
2016/04/26 15:23:19 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Cannot find .className property for htmlParser, using default
2016/04/26 15:23:19 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/html is
2016/04/26 15:23:19 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for application/xhtml+xml is
2016/04/26 15:23:19 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for application/xml is
2016/04/26 15:23:19 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/xml is
2016/04/26 15:23:19 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/vnd.wap.wml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.RegexpHTMLParser
2016/04/26 15:23:19 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHCAbstractImpl: Local host =  hostname.ula.comcast.net
2016/04/26 15:23:19 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC3Impl: HTTP request retry count = 0
2016/04/26 15:23:19 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Creating summariser <summary>
2016/04/26 15:23:19 INFO  - jmeter.engine.DistributedRunner: Configuring remote engine: 10.xxx.xx.xx:443
2016/04/26 15:24:19 ERROR - jmeter.engine.DistributedRunner: Failed to create engine at 10.xxx.xx.xx:443 java.rmi.ConnectIOException: error during JRMP connection establishment; nested exception is:
        java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:304)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:340)
        at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
        at java.rmi.Naming.lookup(Naming.java:101)
        at org.apache.jmeter.engine.ClientJMeterEngine.getEngine(ClientJMeterEngine.java:54)
        at org.apache.jmeter.engine.ClientJMeterEngine.<init>(ClientJMeterEngine.java:67)
        at org.apache.jmeter.engine.DistributedRunner.createEngine(DistributedRunner.java:237)
        at org.apache.jmeter.engine.DistributedRunner.getClientEngine(DistributedRunner.java:213)
        at org.apache.jmeter.engine.DistributedRunner.init(DistributedRunner.java:91)
        at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.runNonGui(JMeter.java:814)
        at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.startNonGui(JMeter.java:737)
        at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.start(JMeter.java:395)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver.main(NewDriver.java:264)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:189)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:254)
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readByte(DataInputStream.java:265)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:246)
        ... 17 more
2016/04/26 15:24:19 INFO  - jmeter.engine.DistributedRunner: Failed to configure 10.xxx.xx.xx:443
2016/04/26 15:24:19 INFO  - jmeter.engine.DistributedRunner: Stopping remote engines
2016/04/26 15:24:19 INFO  - jmeter.engine.DistributedRunner: Remote engines have been stopped
2016/04/26 15:24:19 ERROR - jmeter.JMeter: Error in NonGUIDriver java.lang.RuntimeException: Following remote engines could not be configured:[10.xxx.xx.xx:443]
        at org.apache.jmeter.engine.DistributedRunner.init(DistributedRunner.java:110)
        at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.runNonGui(JMeter.java:814)
        at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.startNonGui(JMeter.java:737)
        at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.start(JMeter.java:395)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver.main(NewDriver.java:264)
`
```

Comment: 10.xxx.xx.xx:443 - is it windows? Are you trying to run in the distributed mode from linux?

Comment: Yes, its windows. I didn't enable the distributed mode in linux. Could port be the issue as I can telnet only on port 443 and not on port 1099. It works fine from Windows but not from linux. The requirement given are 1. its a web service 2. hostname - xxx.xxx.com 3. portnum 443 4. username and password details

Comment: Is the jemter-server running on 443 port?

Comment: I am directly trying to connect from the jmeter client to the Webservice which is running on port 443.

Comment: -R stands for remote server. You provide you jmeter server to this option. The details of your webservice will be inside jmx file

Comment: Sorry my mistake. Thanks for correcting it. I removed the -R option and it seems to be returning the result fine.

Comment: I want to introduce a delay when there is a failure connecting to this webservice. I tried constant timer but it is introducing a delay to the 1st iteration as well. 1. Can we avoid that. 2. How to send a mail after 3 failure attempts. Is BeanShell Preprocessor the preferred method.

Comment: I am new to Jmeter. So need some help in setting up this loop. I am using a while loop controller which should execute until ( "${Count}" < 3)} Can I use a Beanshell Assertion with the following code. int Count=0; if (ResponseCode.equals("200") == true) { Failure=false ; print("test success"); } else { Failure=true; print("test failure"); Count=Count+1; System.out.println("Count="+Count); }. But the loop doesn't increment the count. I tried Beanshell PostProcessor as well but not helping.